# Avoid password prompt while using minicom

Tags: sudo, serial-port, visudo, minicom

I have the following python code where I am trying to open the device `/dev/ttyUSB5` using `minicom`:

```
import serial
import os
b1_ser_port_num=5
cmd="/dev/ttyUSB"+str(b1_ser_port_num)
print "We are now accessing the serial port : ",cmd
os.system("sudo minicom -D "+cmd+" -b 115200\n")
```

The above still throws the password prompt at the terminal when I run it. Before doing the above, I had made sure that I added the user to the `sudo` group by doing the following:

```
user4@user-pc-4:~$ sudo gpasswd -a user4 sudo
[sudo] password for user4: 
Adding user user4 to group sudo
```

I also added the following to `/etc/sudoers` file to ensure that `user4` doesn't get prompted for password in order to get access to the serial port `/dev/ttyUSB5` through `minicom` :

```
user4 ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/minicom
```

What is going wrong here? How can I disable the password prompt for a specific program without giving the user a complete privilege? I have a feeling I'm missing some piece of information - either with `/etc/sudoers` or with `/dev/ttyUSB5`.

Comment: Have you tried adding `user4 ` to the `dialout` group and avoiding `sudo` altogether?

Comment: I just did that. Now, password is not prompted for. But the port `/dev/ttyUSB5` has become unresponsive after that! Help!